# get correct url from feature

Tags: 2010, feature-activation

To make it simple as the title suggest I want the correct url from the feature!

atm when i was testing in test eviroment it worked well! I got the url using:

```
SPSite siteCollection = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;
```

moving on, I then started on my test server but it still is getting the url from my vpc? am i missing somthing?

my vpc url is `http://mysite`

my test url is `http://welcome`

when i activate the feature on test it throws an exception stating that the url `http://mysite` doesnt exist! but i know that beacuse im not on that server and the feature is not running on that server as its under `http://welcome` arrrrrrrhhhhh.

so is there somthing that im missing? like some caching that i dont know of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LOL man i must be tired! well solved the issue! i cant belive its related to the account that i was using was not in the WSS_ADMIN_WPG group!

WOW they could of made it more obvious!

also like to note that I was updating the quicklinks dynamicly from a list, i got the same error when using a url that doesnt exist LOL soooo bad but iv learnt from it ;)

also like to note that you can get the same error from quick links as i was doing above but if the url is external it will throw an error as below! you need to check a checkbox in site settings to say that the links are external! that way it wont concat your links aswell

the error that i got was:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The Web application at http://*****:8437 could not be found. Verify that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be serving existing content, the system administrator may need to add a new request URL mapping to the intended application.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(SPFarm farm, Uri requestUri, Boolean contextSite, SPUserToken userToken)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(String requestUrl)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetServerRelativeUrlFromUrl(String fullOrRelativeUrl, Boolean includeQueryString, Boolean canonicalizeUrl)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPNavigationNode.AddInternal(Int32 iPreviousNodeId, Int32 iParentId, Boolean bAddToQuickLaunch)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPNavigationNodeCollection.AddInternal(SPNavigationNode node, Int32 iPreviousNodeId)
   at *****.InheritQuickLinks.Features.Feature1.Feature1EventReceiver.AddQuickLaunchItem(String header, String url, SPWeb web)
   at *****.InheritQuickLinks.Features.Feature1.Feature1EventReceiver.FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: You need to read before posting! i am the author for one and two the above solved my issue at hand! "account that i was using was not in the WSS_ADMIN_WPG group" that is the answer! i dont know how more clear i need to be ;)

Comment: Ahh, my bad. Got this in the review section which grays out the question. But by the wording it looked more of a midnight facebook post than an actual answer. Sorry about that :)

Comment: lol its no probs! partly my problem! was frustrated and in a rush to answer the question! Im tiered and annoyed that iv spent alot of time for somthing so silly! :(